# What are the maximum data capacities of the active rovers on Mars?

Tags: mars, rovers, perseverance, curiosity, zhurong

Many rovers have been sent to Mars and, as now, some are still working there. Does anyone know the maximum data capacity of each active rover?

1. Curiosity
2. Perseverance
3. Zhurong

Comment: I suppose "data capacity" means the peak bitrate that these rovers can send back (and not the capacity of the rover's data storage buffer). My interpretation means that this is the system capability to repatriate data from Mars (rover+ supporting deep space network).

Comment: @NgPh - I supposed the opposite (max storage on board). Perhaps the OP could clarify?

Comment: ...which would probably leave Ingenuity as the winner, as instead of robust, low-density, high-reliability radiation-proof antique memories it uses modern off-the-shelf components which quite likely go into hundreds of gigabytes.

Comment: ...found it. 32GB flash memory on Ingenuity. I wonder how the rovers compare to that.

Comment: Haha. Found data for Curiosity and Perseverance. Both have 2GB of flash. Now just to find out about Zhurong!

Comment: @SF.: Please go ahead and post that as a partial answer.  The information on Zhurong might not be available.

Comment: @SF, This much advance rover only have 2GB Flash... I thought New rover have 100 or 1000TB

Comment: @HelloZero005: Where would NASA have bought a 1000TB radiation-hardened, space-rated, NASA-certified Flash drive in 2005? Such a thing doesn't even exist in 2021.

Comment: @HelloZero005 the primary method of radiation-hardening is use of technology of density sufficiently low that a hit of a cosmic ray is incapable of flipping a bit - the electric charges in capacitors, transistors etc is sufficient to be read out as the same  "0" or "1" as it was written even if a cosmic ray adds some of the charge. Modern, high-density electronics is vulnerable here, the tiny components operating on currents and charges low enough a strike of a cosmic ray will generate a current strong enough it will read as a clear valid signal, I don't know how Ingenuity deals with it

Comment: @SF (also Jorg W Mittag) Perhaps, a companion question: how much each instrument on each rover needs as temporary storage, by NASA standard. It seems obvious that cameras will require most (cf sizing for Ingenuity). It's puzzling that NASA tries to save mass or cost to limit Perseverance flash storage to 2GB. At least, adding 2 to 8 such memory cards would not make a budget over-run (?). We are talking about non-critical temporary storage, right?

Comment: @NgPh I think you're imagining the 2GB as a chip one would find in a thumb drive, maybe larger. You should rather think of it as a [2GB expansion card to SGI Onyx](https://hardware.majix.org/computers/sgi.onyx/images/onyx.40.big.jpg).

Comment: @NgPh: The reason why Ingenuity has such a large storage capacity is that it is cobbled together from off-the-shelf components. It was a very late addition, thrown together as fast and cheap as possible. Perseverance is a billion dollar space-rated machine, practically identical to Curiosity with only small updates – Curiosity was designed in the early 2000s, so that's (mostly) the technology level Perseverance is at. Compare: Perseverance is using a RAD750 CPU, which is a radiation-hardened single-core PPC 750 (aka G3) running at 200 MHz. Ingenuity has a 4-core 64 bit ARM running at 2.4GHz.

Comment: Looking at these numbers I have a funny feeling Curiosity could benefit from off-loading some of computational work to Ingenuity and also use it as a mobile external data storage device.

Comment: @SF, looks like your are thinking of RAM capacity. I am thinking of "mass storage" (slow memory). BTW, even if rad-hardened chips are required for mission-critical, costwise would it not be beneficial to add some COTS backup memory ("if it fails, bad luck, who cares")?

Comment: @NgPh No, I'm thinking about mass storage, I used a RAM board photo because it's representative of the style of circuitry you can expect. In particular, when Curiosity was being designed, Flash chips of 16MB were starting to overtake 8MB ones, and 128MB were a bleeding-edge invention. So imagine a 2GB board comprised of 16MB chips.

Comment: @SF Found from NASA this [architectural computer spec](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/rover/brains/). Correct me if I am wrong, but the 2GB capacity doesn't look like it is for a function of DRAM.

Comment: @NgPh No, but I really don't understand your point. It's mass storage flash. It's 2GB. If we add 8 such cards, as you suggested, for 16GB of RAM, that's 1024 16MB chips, or 128 experimental, bleeding-edge at that time 128MB chips. Large power consumption, considerable mass, heat production, size, and all that for what purpose? Around that time I bought my first own hard disk for Amiga, it was 200MB and I could install programs from hundreds of floppies on it!

Comment: @HelloZero005: Also, consider that only data that is sent to Earth can be analyzed. Even if Perseverance had your hypothetical 1PB flash memory, it would take almost 127 *years* to transmit all that data to Earth, and that is assuming the use of Perseverance's fastest communication link, and that Perseverance does nothing but transmit data every second of every day, without doing any science whatsoever. But the MMRTG which provides power only lasts for 14 years. Also, if Perseverance spends all its time transmitting data and not doing science, then there's nothing interesting to transmit!

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Still briliant NASA engineers couldent make a Hi Speed Data Transfer Systems for Mars rovers, Even Thier Spending Billions of Dollers for Rovers????

Comment: @HelloZero005: Perseverance's maximum data rate is 2 MBit/s over a distance of 55000000000 meters. The maximum data rate for WiFi when Perseverance was designed was, I believe, 11 MBit/s over a distance of 100m (maybe 54 MBit/s). Considering that signal strength degrades with the square of the distance, Transmitting data over 55000000000 meters is roughly 300000000000000000 times harder than over 100m. So, they managed to get 1/27 to 1/6 the data rate with 300000000000000000 times the signal attenuation. I think that's pretty good.

Comment: NASA Should Send a More powerful Data Transmitting Station to Mars. so no communication Problems in Future Missions.

Comment: @HelloZero005 Yeah, more powerful, with more powerful power generators, transmitting and receiving antennas, stronger amplifiers, and as result much heavier than existing ones... meaning launch cost proportionally higher. And where are they going to get the money from? Considering these "billions of dollars" are insufficient for that?

Comment: @SF. from US Tax Payers, they will pay

Comment: anyone know about the Zhurong Rover Details?